# CNN box can't exceed original image size error

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm out of my wits here. I've been working on this classifier that would move images acc to people in them but can't seem to move past classifying 2 people correctly.
the model :

---

## Model: "sequential_4"

Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #

conv2d_8 (Conv2D)            (None, 86, 86, 128)       3584

---

max_pooling2d_8 (MaxPooling2 (None, 43, 43, 128)       0

---

dropout_14 (Dropout)         (None, 43, 43, 128)       0

---

conv2d_9 (Conv2D)            (None, 15, 15, 256)       295168

---

max_pooling2d_9 (MaxPooling2 (None, 7, 7, 256)         0

---

dropout_15 (Dropout)         (None, 7, 7, 256)         0

---

flatten_4 (Flatten)          (None, 12544)             0

---

dense_9 (Dense)              (None, 256)               3211520

---

dropout_16 (Dropout)         (None, 256)               0

---

dense_10 (Dense)             (None, 512)               131584

---

dropout_17 (Dropout)         (None, 512)               0

---

dense_11 (Dense)             (None, 1)                 513

Total params: 3,642,369
Trainable params: 3,642,369
Non-trainable params: 0

every time I try to run `runner.fit(training_set, steps_per_epoch = 6, epochs = 1, validation_data=test)`

i get the error :`ValueError: box can't exceed original image size`

can anyone explain why this is happening and ways to fix it,
ps: I know about bounding box regression and I don't know how this is related to that. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: what data processing are you doing on your data? I think the error is coming from there and not the neural network code.

Comment: @Netim since i am low on data i'm using tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator to make some from the available data. apart from that nothing else is done to the data itself.

Comment: Please let us know the image shape you are using for model training as well the number of images (dataset size). Also please add some minimal reproducible code to understand the error.